# EffectLiteR: Why does an empty output occur?

Tags: r, output, structural-equation-model

I have the problem that RStudio shows me only an empty output after executing my script.

[image]

The "funny" thing is that the correct results appear when I write the commands in the console and execute them directly in the console.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get the results and not an empty output after running the script?

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

{r,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
    
library(EffectLiteR)
library(mice)
    
d <- readRDS(file="sophonet_tmp.rds")

effectLite(y="lsas.a.t2.miss", x="tb", data=d, method="sem")
```

I tried a lot of things. Reinstalling `EffectLiteR`, Updating RStudio, Updating Rtools. I also tried to save the markdown-file as an html. Interestingly R shows the correct result (and not an empty output) in the html file.